# Canvas нужно сделать кликабельным

Tags: javascript, html

Есть canvas 1000 на 1000. Как обработать проведение по нему мышкой с зажатой ЛКМ (нужно знать x и y наведения)?

Answer (score -2):

Для отлавливания позиции курсора используйте обработчик [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event), в нём вы можете получить позицию курсора на экране, за счёт возвращаемого события [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), в котором содержатся свойство [`clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) и [`clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY):

```js
element.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY) // Выведет позицию курсора по X и Y
})
```

Но данное событие будет выполняться постоянно.
Чтобы это происходило лишь тогда, когда зажата клавиша <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>, нужно создать переменную, которая будет разрешать выполнять какие-то действия при событии `mousemove`.

Для этого воспользуемся обработчиком [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) - это событие отрабатывает когда произошло нажатие на кнопку мыши. Событие возвращает `MouseEvent`, в котором содержится свойство [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button), где значение `0` - является клавишей <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>

```js
element.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  console.log(event.button === 0) // выведет TRUE если нажата ЛКМ, в остальных случаях FALSE
})
```

Чтобы поменять значение переменной на обратное, используем событие, которое отработает, когда клавиша мыши будет отпущена - [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event).

Так же, советую, передавать функцию, которая будет передаваться в `mouseup`, в событие [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event), чтобы прекратить действие, когда курсор выйдет за пределы элемента, в вашем случае - это Canvas.

---

Ниже я добавляю пример простой "рисовалки" на Canvas, где реализована нужная автору механика.

```js
const can = document.querySelector('#can') // Получаем элемент canvas
const ctx = can.getContext('2d') // Получаем контекст canvas
let isDraw = false // флаг, благодаря которому будем отслеживать когда надо рисовать, а когда нет

// Надстройки
ctx.lineJoin = 'round' // форма вершин
ctx.lineCap = 'round' // форма концов линии
ctx.lineWidth = 5 // толщина линии

// Функция отрисовки линии
const CanvasDraw = (event) => {
  const rect = can.getBoundingClientRect() // получаем позицию canvas относительно вьюпорта
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left // Получаем позицию курсора на экране по X, вычитаем отступ от canvas от края экрана, получаем X позицию курсора на canvas
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top // Аналогично с вычислением выше
  ctx.lineTo(x, y) // выставляем новую позицию линию, по позиции курсора, от предыдущей точки
  ctx.stroke() // отрисовываем линию
}

// Функция начала рисования
const CanvasDrawStart = (event) => {
  // Определяем, что нажата именно ЛКМ
  if(event.button === 0) {
    isDraw = true // меняем флаг
    CanvasDraw(event) // отрисосываем первую точку
  }
}

// Функция для отключения рисования
const CanvasDrawStop = (event) => {
  isDraw = false // меняем флаг
  ctx.beginPath() // закрываем предыдущие пути, чтобы можно было рисовать новые
}

can.addEventListener('mousedown', CanvasDrawStart) // вешаем обработчик при нажатии кнопки мыши
can.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => isDraw ? CanvasDraw(event) : false) // вешаем обработчик при движении мыши
can.addEventListener('mouseup', CanvasDrawStop) // вешаем обработчик при отпускании клавиши мыши
can.addEventListener('mouseout', CanvasDrawStop) // вешаем обработчик, если вышли за границу canvas
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

canvas {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: Минус без причины, признак дурачины..

Comment: @user564501, о чём речь, можно поподробнее?